# How do I get one those avatars made from random patterns?

Tags: support, profile-picture

I made a new account on Super User, and I was rewarded with this totally stupid dog as my avatar.

[image: doggy cool]

Others have nice anonymous bit-map patterns in funky colours. I want that too! How can I get such an unobtrusive speckle pattern?

I don't want to sign up with Gravatar if you consider putting that in your answer. I just want the association with the stupid dog removed.

Comment: Is it friday afternoon yet?

Comment: By the way, you don't need an email address in order to use the site.

Comment: You seem to have fixed this... care to share the totally stupid dog pic so we can appropriately ridicule it for not being a pony?

Comment: That dog is either snowboarding, riding a Harley or a fighter pilot. All cool. Why hate on the dog?

Comment: @Diago, here in Belgium it is. We live in another timezone, and another weekzone. Today it is friday here.

Comment: Stupid dogs need the most love.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove your email address and you too can be of the [identicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon) brigade!

The dog is in your avatar because you've signed up with Gravatar at one point and put him in that kennel.

If you've never signed up with Gravatar then you're probably using an email address that has at one point.

Comment: I never signed up with Gravatar. I guess these sites copy a gravatar icon from a very generic name as bert.

Comment: Removing the e-mail helped. It was a standard trash-email address from mailinator, so I guess some made a gravatar for that e-mail address some time in some other dimension.

Comment: spamgourmet.com is good for spam email protection. It forwards email to your email address based on counts / rules / trusted sites etc. So you can set stackoverflow as the only site that can send email through that spamgourmet email address